# Multiple y-axis values against one single x-axis point

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have implemented AMCharts JS library in one of my web apps and am having an issue. Right now i need to add multiple y-axis values to one single x-axis point (which is actually a date). I have  5 values 5,1,5,4,1,3 which contain same x-axis point (same date) but when i observe the graph sometimes 4 is missing while sometimes 5 as shown in the image. Am i really doing something wrong? This is the form of data

```
{date: "2016-03-29", value: 5}
{date: "2016-03-29", value: 1}
{date: "2016-03-29", value: 5}
{date: "2016-03-29", value: 4}
{date: "2016-03-29", value: 1}
{date: "2016-03-29", value: 3}
{date: "2016-10-20", value: 0}
{date: "2016-10-20", value: 0}
{date: "2016-10-20", value: 0}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your setup.

First, your data is structured incorrectly for a chart with [`parseDates`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#parseDates) enabled. You can't have multiple elements of the same date. AmCharts requires that you group your data points if they share the same date/category. This is by design and every single example on the website shows this, so all of your 2016-03-29 and 2016-10-20 points can be reduced into two objects. I'm presuming that those multiple values correspond to different graph objects, so you need unique value fields for each, i.e.

```
[{
  date: "2016-03-29",
  value1: 5,
  value2: 1,
  value3: 5,
  value4: 4,
  value5: 1,
  value6: 3
}, {
  date: "2016-10-20"
  value1: 0,
  value2: 0,
  value3: 0
}]
```

And then you have 6 graph objects with valueFields set to value1 through value6 to accommodate for those points. Again, I'm assuming that you have multiple graphs given your dataset.

*Edit*

Your comment indicates that this is not the case and they all belong to one graph. You still need to restructure your data and give unique timestamps since you can't have multiple entries with the same timestamp for a `parseDates`-enabled chart. If those values came in at different times, then provide that information. For example, assuming your data is hourly:

```
{date: "2016-03-29 01:00", value: 5}
{date: "2016-03-29 02:00", value: 1}
{date: "2016-03-29 03:00", value: 5}
{date: "2016-03-29 04:00", value: 4}
{date: "2016-03-29 05:00", value: 1}
{date: "2016-03-29 06:00", value: 3}
{date: "2016-10-20 01:00", value: 0}
{date: "2016-10-20 02:00", value: 0}
{date: "2016-10-20 03:00", value: 0}
```

This will work but you have to set your [`dataDateFormat`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#dataDateFormat) to match the timestamp (in this case `"YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN"`) and adjust your [`minPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) to accommodate for the smallest interval in between your points (for this example: `"hh"`).

If you don't parse dates, then you can keep your setup, but the chart will look weird with multiple 2016-03-29 entries. Those are your only options.

As for displaying multiple value axes, a value axis needs to be associated with a graph. If you need multiple value axes, then you need multiple graphs. Each graph's [`valueAxis`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#valueAxis) property needs to be assigned to a valueAxis object or [valueAxis `id`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#id). You can't assign multiple value axes to one graph object. You can see how this works in [this example](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-value-axes/).

If you only have one graph and need to display a second value axis, create a duplicate graph instance and disable visual aspects of it, like so:

```
  valueAxes: [{
    "position": "left",
    "id": "v1"
  }, {
    "position": "right",
    "id": "v2"
  }],
  graphs: [{
    //initial graph
    type: "line",
    bullet: "round",
    valueField: "value"
  }, {
    //invisible duplicate graph
    //for second axis
    lineAlpha: 0,
    showBalloons: false,
    visibleInLegend: false,
    valueAxis: "v2",
    valueField: "value"
  }],
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/f30443d7dcad795b8cdf1990a1a3a1ee?editors=0010)

Comment: Actually my data not just limited to 6 values max against one date, it can be 15 or maybe mare. Secondly i m not using multiple graphs for this, i want single graph to accommodate all these points. I have second graph but that is just to draw a trend line (median of all the y-axis values against one single date) which is not directly related to first graph.

Comment: Like I said, you can't have multiple points on the same exact date with no timestamp on just one graph. AmCharts isn't designed for that. If your values are associated with multiple different timestamps on that date (2016-03-26 01:00, 2016-03-26 02:00, etc), that will work, hence my comment about adding different timestamps and changing your dataDateFormat and minPeriod to recognize them.The point still stands about having multiple y axes - they each need a unique graph.

Comment: If you only have one graph, then duplicate it and assign it to the second value axis. You'll want to disable all the visual aspects of it as well. [Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/f30443d7dcad795b8cdf1990a1a3a1ee?editors=0010)